# The RegReplace Sublime Text 3 plugin is not doing anything

Tags: sublime-text-3

I need to do several replacements in many files so I was looking for a "batch find and replace" tool and this RegReplace for Sublime Text 3 plugin looks promising, but I can't get it working.

Here is what I have done:

1. installed RegReplace using PackageControl: Install package
2. edited file Preferences->PackageSettings->RegReplace->Settings-User:

   ```
   {
     "replacements": {
       "remove_a": {
         "find" : "a",
         "replace": "",
         "greedy": true
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. opened a file containing some text
4. opened the console
5. typed `view.run_command('reg_replace',{"replacements": ["remove_a"]})`
   but nothing happened (I expected that letters "a" in the file would be removed)
6. edited file Preferences->PackageSettings->RegReplace->Commands-User:

   ```
   [
     {
       "caption": "Remove a",
       "command": "reg_replace",
       "args": {
         "replacements": ["remove_a"]
        }
     }
   ]
   ```
7. Ran the command "Remove a" from Command Palette. Again, nothing
   happened.

Is there anything that could be done to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following text in `Preferences -> PackageSettings -> RegReplace -> Rules-User`, and save the file:

```
{
    "replacements":
    {
        "remove_a":
        {
            "find": "a",
            "name": "remove_a",
            "replace": "",
            "greedy": true
        }
    }
}
```

Then, execute the `view.run_command('reg_replace',{"replacements": ["remove_a"]})` command from the Console, as you had done in your step `5`.

Alternatively, you can create your new rule by doing the following (you may find it easier to create new rules this way):

1. Open the Command Palette (in Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Type: `regrep`
3. Select the **RegReplace: Create New Regular Expression Rule** option
4. In the "settings panel" that opens, configure the following settings (include the double-quotes):

   - name = "remove_a"
   - find = "a"
   - replace = ""
   - greedy = True
5. With the cursor still in the "settings panel", press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the settings
6. To close the "settings panel", press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key

Once a rule has been created via either of the above methods, it can be edited via the Command Palette's **RegReplace: Edit Regular Expression Rule** option, which will allow you to select one of the existing named rules to edit.

Reference: The "**A Better Way To Create Regex Rules**" section in the [User Guide](http://facelessuser.github.io/RegReplace/usage/).